# How can I return two percentage values for progress bars in 1 function call?

Tags: javascript, html

My landing page is going to have progress percentages for each of the technologies I know. The only solution I can seem to figure out is making two functions with different values for each of them and then call them both in the body onload. This seems extremely messy. How could I make this better?

```js
function webMove() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
  var width = 0;
  var width2 = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);

  function frame() {
    if (width >= 50) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++;
      elem.style.width = width + '%';
      elem.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
    }
  }
}


function gitHubMove() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar2");
  var width = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);

  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++;
      elem.style.width = width + '%';
      elem.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="webMove(),gitHubMove()">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="myProgress">
      <div id="myBar">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="container2">
    <div id="myProgress2">
      <div id="myBar2">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: can you collaborate with working code example on codepen?

Comment: why cant you merge the two?

Comment: `<body onload="webMove('myBar');webMove('myBar2');">`. `function webMove(elemid){...}`

Comment: https://codepen.io/glrose/pen/KeQWro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You like dry code, that is very good habit. There you have small modification of your code:

```js
function progressBar(elementId, progressPercent){
    var elem = document.getElementById(elementId);
    var width = 0;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 10);

    function frame() {
        if (width >= progressPercent) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            width++;
            elem.style.width = width + '%';
            elem.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
        }
    }
}
progressBar("webMove", 80)
progressBar("gitHubMove", 60)
```

```html
    <div id="container">
        <div id="myProgress">
            <div id="webMove">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="container2">
        <div id="myProgress2">
            <div id="gitHubMove">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: this still requires 2 function calls

Comment: @JohnRuddell Make a function that calls them both-seems pretty straight-forward.

Comment: @DaveNewton or write a better function that updates them concurrently so you dont have multiple intervals running.

Comment: and then put data into object and forEach() it :-]

Answer (score 1):

just define an object to track what you want to. this is a potential solution for as many progress bars you want, and its performant because there is only one interval running. I added a start in the object that currently isn't utilized but if you wanted to have the start of the progress be something other than 0 thats how you can do it

```js
 function progress() {
        keys = ['web', 'github']
        var meta = {
          web: {
            done: false,
            current: 0,
            max: 50,
            start: 0,
            elem: document.getElementById("myBar")
          },
          github: {
            done: false,
            current: 0,
            max: 100,
            start: 0,
            elem: document.getElementById("myBar2")
          }
        }
        var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
        
        function frame() {
          var complete = true
          keys.forEach( function(key) {
            var obj = meta[key]
            if (!obj.done) {
              complete = false
            }
            if (obj.current >= obj.max) {
              obj.done = true
              return
            }
    
            obj.current++
            obj.elem.style.width = obj.current + '%';
            obj.elem.innerHTML = obj.current * 1 + '%';
          })
          if (complete) {
            clearInterval(id)
          }
        }
    }
    progress()
```

```html
<div id="myBar"></div>
<div id="myBar2"></div>
```